# Use DC/DNS servers only for AD domain queries?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, group-policy

I have two branch offices without any local servers. Each office is connected to HQ with VPN tunnels.

Is it possible to configure the computers in those locations to use the DNS servers at HQ only for AD related queries, and send all other queries to the local router?

For example, if the AD domain is company.xyz, the client would send a query for server.company.xyz to 10.1.1.2.

But, the client would send a query for localnewspaper.com to 192.168.1.1.

Could this be achieved with the Name Resolution Policy Table?

If so, would it be a good idea for HQ as well?

Would it affect DDNS registrations?

Comment: You could use your local router as a DNS, and make the router lookup on the remote DNS server, the important detail there is that the router will cache the result, so he will not always go to remote server for the resolution.

Comment: I considered this, but wasn’t sure how it would affect DDNS registration by the domain joined clients.

Comment: This was the final solution, and it works perfectly. Windows clients still dynamically register their records. I had to tweak it a little with GPO, but 2+ years since, and no issues.

Comment: Hi, happy to hear it worked. I will write it as an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your local router as a DNS, and make the router lookup on the remote DNS server, the important detail there is that the router will cache the result, so he will not always go to remote server for the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you need this: is it to reduce the load on the AD server?
Many enterprises specify a DNS server system such as Infoblox as their primary resolver and then within it they specify forwarders whereby companyname.xyz is sent to AD. 
DDNS update comes via DHCP and in the DHCP config it would specify which server(s) to notify about DDNS.

Comment: The goals would be to, prevent a VPN outage from killing all DNS resolution & make non-AD domain querys faster. I’m not using the MS DHCP server at the remote sites, I’m using the ISC DHCP server, so I’m not sure if it can do DDNS registrations on behalf of Windows clients. I currently have the clients registering themselves.

Comment: If you have remote sites with poor connectivity, surely you would have local DCs or at least RODCs?

Comment: These remote sites only have a few clients, and are temporary. So servers in those locations are not practical.

Comment: Then I would suggest using the approach I outlined. This guide explains how to do the DDNS https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270097/isc-dhcp-with-active-directory-secure-dynamic-dns-updates

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, there's no way to make this work. This breaks DNS resolution for AD and breaks Dynamic DNS registration.

Comment: Seems like this would be a nice feature to add to Windows. Offloading all DNS querys for non-AD related zones to another DNS server could be better for performance and security.